# Testcafe - Unable to click on login button

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am trying to automate logging into Guidewire policy center application. I am able to enter the username and password but the click for login button is not working.
I have tried (commented code)
-normal click
-double click
-scroll to element and then click and then double click. (All code below)
-another option of using clientfunction but none of them are working.
There is no problem with the identifier/path of the element.

```
import {Selector, t} from 'testcafe';
import {ClientFunction} from 'testcafe';

fixture('Getting Started')
.page('http://localhost:8180/pc/PolicyCenter.do');
//const element=Selector('#Login-LoginScreen-LoginDV-submit > div').withText('Log In');
const clickSubmit = ClientFunction(() => {    
 document.querySelector("#Login-LoginScreen-LoginDV-submit > div > div.gw-label")
});


test('Login', async t=>{
    await 
   .typeText('#Login-LoginScreen-LoginDV-username > div > input','su')
    .wait(1000)
    .typeText('#Login-LoginScreen-LoginDV-password > div > input','pw')
    .wait(1000);
    await element.with({ visibilityCheck: true }).with({timeout: 10000})
  // .setNativeDialogHandler(() => true) .click(clickSubmit)
  //.scroll(element)
  //.click(element)
  //.doubleClick(element)
  clickSubmit()
   await t.wait(5000);
});
```

Comment: It's difficult to understand the cause of the problem without a full simple sample. Please share simple code of the page you tested. If you don't want to do it here, you can [share your code in the TestCafe repo](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A+bug&template=bug_report.yaml).

Comment: The application i am testing is a licensed software.

Comment: We'll be happy to help, but I'm afraid we cannot find a solution without a simple example.